# Pooling Web Workers

Tags: javascript, html, pooling, web-worker

Does anyone know of good patterns/libraries for pooling Web Workers?

I want to be able to do something like the following:

- Set a maximum number of threads.
- The first time I ask for a Worker it creates a new one.
- The next time it will return the previous Worker, unless it is still completing operations, in which case it will create a new one and return that.
- Once we hit the maximum it starts queuing requests for workers up and starting them when a Worker becomes available.
- This currently assumes the pool would all use the same .js file.

Or is there a better approach to this?

Comment: Will all these workers be running the same .js file?

Comment: Good point - in this case yes. I guess you'd need separate pools for different .js files. I'll update the question to mention that.

Comment: jQuery Hive: https://github.com/rwldrn/jquery-hive

Comment: Off topic for stackoverflow? Bizarre.

Comment: @AndyHume This is a really good question - I've got no idea why it's been closed

Comment: are you kidding me? what about this is off topic? why is this closed?